# How do I turn %H into an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

On Python I've been working on a bit of code that looks at the time and compares it to another time and says how long it will be until that time arrives. A solution I came up with was to just do some simple subtraction to get the result but to find the hour I would use "%H" and convert it into an integer but python doesn't like that. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: just put it in `int()`

Comment: It is quite hard to understand your required flow. Did you try to use the datetime library?

Comment: Can you clarify what data you are working with? You cannot "turn %H into an integer" because it isn't one. At most it is an instruction to *format* a number/time.

Comment: *You* don't use `%H`; that's just a string argument to some function that uses it to extract *part* of an input string. Whatever *that* function returns contains something you can turn into (or may already be) an `int`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize pandas to make things easier for you.

```
A = pd.Timestamp('14:26:32')
B = pd.Timestamp('18:54:17')

C = (B-A).total_seconds()/3600 # 4.4625 hours
```

Then just convert to `int`.

```
int(C) # 4 hours
```

Comment: `pandas` is a pretty heavy dependency if you don't actually need anything else from it. Don't drag that in when the standard `datetime` module could work just as well.